# Compose functions in the prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is a conceptual question I wasn't skillful to solve.

The whole question can be reduced to this line:

```
OurConstructor.prototype = {
   a: function(){},
   b: function(){ a(); }
};
```

Can we call `a()` inside `b()`, both being on the prototype?

---

**Edit:** Just for other people, I was calling `this.a()` with the wrong name, but using  `b: function(){ this.a(); }` should work just fine.

Comment: I dont think you should be attaching that to the prototype..

Comment: You mean because of the constructor? Well, but that's another topic. I just tried to make things brief.

Comment: @TiiJ7 I believe that answer is false, I've tried that already

Comment: ```  var OurConstructor = function(){
}

OurConstructor.prototype.a = function() {
  console.log('func a')
}

OurConstructor.prototype.b = function() {
  this.a();
  console.log('func b')
}

const ourConst = new OurConstructor();
ourConst.b()
 ```

Comment: To answer your question: In this current case. It will result in an error. Because a() is not inside the scope of b. In order to run a. You will have to call it with the "this" keyword.

Comment: @misternobody it s not false, check my comment above, your question is a duplicate

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Yes, I should have included that, the problem is I've tried already, so I'm quite surprised. I will test again.

Comment: @EugenSunic mate slow down, I've tried that already, and it's simple. For some reason it didn't work, so i'm checking where is the difference.

Comment: I tried the following and it works: 
OurConstructor.prototype = { a: function( ){ console.log('asdf') }, b:function( ){ this.a()} }
OurConstructor.prototype.b();

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I am accessing other values from the prototype on those functions. I know it works in this example, I tried to keep it simple and that's why there is a misunderstood.

Comment: Not sure why anyone is voting to re-open this...it is a complete duplicate fully answered in the other question